# Command for roles in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a verify system for my discord bot, where one does c.verify to get the Verified role, but I am having trouble with giving the role, and everything that I have found doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def verify(self, ctx):
        role = get(ctx.author.roles, name="TOS Verified")
        if ctx.channel.id == 769016529450303519:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} has been verified.")
            sleep(1)
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
            await bot.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send("You can not verify here.")
```

the error that I am getting is "bot has no attribute add_roles". everything works up until it has to add the role, but i dont know why i cant add the role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let us start from the top,

```
role = get(ctx.author.roles, name="TOS Verified")
```

Right here you're trying to get a Role called `TOS Verified` from the person who runs the command which makes no sense because if they are trying to verify they wouldn't have that Role. We actually want to get this from the guild's roles like so:

```
role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="TOS Verified")
```

The second problem

```
await bot.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
```

`Bot` doesn't have an [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) attribute, looking at the docs it tells us that it is actually a method of Member. In your case, your Member object would be `ctx.author`.

```
await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: i have done that, and now the error that I am getting is "Unknown Role" Is there a way I can find the role by ID? I believe that it is an issue with the fact that it isnt grabbing the role correctly because I am only giving it the name, even though I copy/pasted it into the code.

Comment: You can get the role by ID using [`get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role), `role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)`